Русский, российский, советский: почему писателей так называют?
Из Ответов Справочной службы
Русский язык, русская литература, русские пословицы и поговорки, русская душа, но: российский флаг, российская конституция, российский парламент.
Вопрос:  Почему так говорится о писателях: русский писатель, русский писатель советского периода, русский советский писатель, русский советский и российский писатель?
Иван Алексеевич Бунин (10 (22) октября 1870 — 8 ноября 1953) — русский писатель, поэт и переводчик, лауреат Нобелевской премии по литературе 1933 года.
Михаил Афанасьевич Булгаков (3 (15) мая 1891 — 10 марта 1940) — русский писатель советского периода, врач, драматург, театральный режиссёр и актёр.
Михаил Александрович Шолохов (24 мая 1905 — 21 февраля 1984) — русский советский писатель, журналист и киносценарист.
Виктор Олегович Пелевин (родился 22 ноября 1962 года, Москва) — русский советский и российский писатель, эссеист.

А вопрос-то в чём? И на Грамоте нет, даже вопросительного знака не найти. В чём подвох?
